# Fortran warning for unintialzed complex numbers

Tags: fortran, compiler-warnings, complex-numbers

I have a fortan function that performs a modular operation on the imaginary part of a complex number. Here it reduces the imaginary part to be -.5

```
complex(KIND=dpc) function mod_2pi(z) result(mod_z)
  complex(KIND=dpc), INTENT(IN) :: z
  mod_z = z-iunit*nint(aimag(z))
end function mod_2pi
```

However, when i run it through the gfortran complier I get the following warning

```
warning: ‘IMAGPART_EXPR <psi>’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     mod_z = z-iunit*nint(aimag(z))
 ^

warning: ‘REALPART_EXPR <psi>’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
      mod_z = z-iunit*nint(aimag(z))
 ^
```

What going wrong? As far a I can see both real and imaginary parts will be initialized? Is there a workaround around this flag without disabling it?

Comment: Do you think it is really worth crippling good code with workarounds because compiler produces bogus warnings? I personally often use `-Wno-maybe-uninitialized` because these bogus warnings are quite common. Not only with complex numbers, but in more situations. What makes me cautious is the `psi`. Do you have such a variable in the calling code? The warning could be at a strange place due to inlining.

Comment: @VladimirF Point taken, no workarounds ;). THe part of coed that calls this functions has the form `psi=mod_2pi(psi)` so there is a `psi` showing up there.

Comment: So you must examine the calling code if there is a code path that may cause `psi ` not to be initialized. The actal function is not important.

Comment: thanks. Sloved it. The culprit was that the initialisation was in a `if(....)then psi=... else psi=... end if` construction. So initialisation was guaranteed, but the compiler got confused.